# como hacer que dependiendo de el tipo de perfil me direccione a el menú correspondiente jsp

Tags: java, jsp, login

HOLA TODOS no se como hacer que dependiendo de el perfil que este en la base de datos me lleve al menú correspondiente cuando ingreso los datos del inicio me direcciona a registro.jsp no que tengo mal espero puedan ayudarme

servlet

```
package servler;

import clases.consultas;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author luisa
 */
public class InicioSesion extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
        String clave = request.getParameter("clave");
        String Perfil = request.getParameter("Perfil");

        consultas co = new consultas();

        if (co.validarIngreso(usuario, clave, Perfil)) {
            HttpSession objesesion = request.getSession(true);
            objesesion.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
             if (Perfil.equals("CLIENTE")) {
                response.sendRedirect("PERFILCLIENTE.jsp");
                   }
                 if (Perfil.equals("GERENCIA")) {
                response.sendRedirect("PERFILGERENCIA.jsp");
                     } else {
                response.sendRedirect("PERFILEMPLEADO.jsp");
                            }

              } else {
                response.sendRedirect("REGISTRO.jsp");
                    }

    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

clase DAO

```
package clases;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.PerRequestFactory;

public class consultas extends ConexionOracle {

    public boolean validarIngreso(String usuario, String clave,String Perfil) {

        PreparedStatement stm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            String CONSULTAS = "SELECT * FROM REGISTRO WHERE ID_NOMBREU=? AND ID_CONTRASEÑA=? AND PERFIL=?";

            stm = ConexionOracle().prepareStatement(CONSULTAS);
            stm.setString(1, usuario);
            stm.setString(2, clave);
            stm.setString(3, Perfil);

            rs = stm.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {

                return true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.err.println(" error " + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (getConnection() != null) {
                    getConnection().close();
                }
                if (stm != null) {
                    stm.close();
                }
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("error 2" + e);
            }
        }

        return false;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        consultas n = new consultas();

        System.out.println(n.validarIngreso("MANU", "LUISASUAZA", "CLIENTE"));
    }

}
```

JSP

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Iniciar Secion</title>

    </head>
    <body><center>

        <h1> Inicio de sesion</h1>

        <form action="iniciar"  method="get" id="forminicio" name="iniciar">

            <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" required="required" /><br>

            <input type="password" name="clave" id="clave" required="required" /><br>
            <%--   <input type="text" name="perfil" id="perfil" required="required" /><br> --%>
                  <% ResultSet rs = null; %>
        <%
            try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdb:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE ", "LUISASUAZA", "1234");
                Statement st = con.createStatement(
                        ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                rs = st.executeQuery("select ID_PERFIL,PERFIL from REGISTRO WHERE PERFIL <> ID_PERFIL ");
                                      
            } catch (Exception e) {
                out.println(e.toString());
                 
            }
        
            while (rs.next()) {
                         
                    }
                        try {
                    %>
         <select  name="Perfil" id="Perfil" required="required"> 
          <%
                        rs.beforeFirst();
                        while (rs.next()) {

                    %>
                    <option>
                        <td align="center" value="<%=rs.getString("PERFIL")%>"><%=rs.getString("ID_PERFIL")%></td>
                        </option>
     <%
                            }
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            out.println(e.toString());
                        }

                    %>
</select>
                <input value="Iniciar Sesiòn" type="submit" id="btniniciar"/> 

                <a href="http://localhost:2016/WebApplication3/REGISTRO.jsp">regis</a>

        </form>
    </body></center>
</html>
```

Comment: Tu usuario es `MANU` y tu clave es `LUISASUAZA` en tu base de datos?

Comment: hola si los tengo tal cual en la base de datos creo que el error esta en la consulta sql pero no se donde